# Google play services error. KIVY, Buildozer- ANDROID

Tags: java, android, kivy

```
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-tvdpi/ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-tvdpi/ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-tvdpi/ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-tvdpi/ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/powered_by_google_dark.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/powered_by_google_light.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_ic_googleplayservices.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/powered_by_google_dark.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/powered_by_google_light.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_full_open_on_phone.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/powered_by_google_dark.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/powered_by_google_light.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-mdpi/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/powered_by_google_dark.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/aBuildfile: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/ultimatepong/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 24.0.2
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: UltimatePong-0.1
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 23.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for UltimatePong-0.1...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for UltimatePong-0.1...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

BUILD FAILED
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:601: Invalid file: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/google-play-services_lib/build.xml

Total time: 2 seconds
pp/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/powered_by_google_light.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/google-play-services_lib/res/drawable-xhdpi/common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/admob/admobmock.pyo
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/admob/admob4android.pyo
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/admob/__init__.pyo
assets/private.mp3: /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/admob/admob4ios.pyo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 517, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 365, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: python build.py --name UltimatePong --version 0.1 --package intellign.ultimatepong --sdk 19 --minsdk 9 --private /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app --permission VIBRATE --permission INTERNET --meta-data com.google.android.gms.version=@integer/google_play_services_version --presplash /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/./presplash.png --icon /home/kivy/Desktop/pong/./appicon.png --orientation landscape debug
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I'm new to kivy and and this my first app, I have spent more than 48 hours trying to figure this out, but I can't so please help me. Thank you

EDIT:
I updated the post with the full log. I'm willing to learn and any type of help will be appreciated.

My goal is to add ads to my game, I used this [code](https://www.theseusmedia.com/blogs/code) as a guideline.

My buildozer.spec file can also be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/FmlXUkOvH1s)

Comment: Please post the full build log.

Comment: @inclement I updated the post with the full log. Thank you!

Comment: Did you edit the build.xml or any other p4a files, as part of trying to make the ads work?

Comment: @inclement Thank you, I got it working with "$ android update lib-project --path <google-play-path> --target android-19" But there is a new error: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086718/admob-rewarded-video-ads-on-kivy-java-android

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with:

```
 $ android update lib-project --path <google-play-path> --target android-19
```