# Admob rewarded video ads on KIVY - Java. Android

Tags: java, android, python, admob, kivy

I'm trying to display google admob rewarded videos on my first game but I can't seem to make it work. This is what I have so far, I don't know Java so this is a very difficult for me. Any help will be appreciated, I'm willing to learn.

```
RewardedVideoAd = autoclass('com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd')
RewardedAds = autoclass('com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds')  

class AdmobAndroid(EventDispatcher):
    mRewardedVideoAd = ObjectProperty(None)
    mRewardedAds = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(AdmobAndroid,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.mRewardedVideoAd = RewardedVideoAd(mactivity)
        self.mRewardedAds = RewardedAds(mactivity)
        self.mRewardedVideoAd = self.mRewardedAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance()
        self.mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener()
        self.mRewardedVideoAd.setAdUnitId(settings.REWARDED_UNIT_ID)


    @run_on_ui_thread
    def request_Rewarded(self):
        if not self.mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded():
            log('REQUESTING rewarded AD')
            adRequestBuilder = AdRequestBuilder()
            adRequest = adRequestBuilder.build()
            self.mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(adRequest)
        else:
            log('NO NEED TO REQUEST rewarded AD,already loaded...')

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def show_Rewarded(self):
        if self.mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded():
            self.mRewardedVideoAd.show()
            return True
        return False
```

This used [this](https://github.com/niavlys/admob4kivy) as a guide.

EDIT*:

```
11-15 04:41:39.858 19683 19701 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 58, in <module>
11-15 04:41:39.860 19683 19701 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/admob/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
11-15 04:41:39.862 19683 19701 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/admob/admob4android.py", line 30, in <module>
11-15 04:41:39.863 19683 19701 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jnius/reflect.py", line 150, in autoclass
11-15 04:41:39.865 19683 19701 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_func.pxi", line 23, in jnius.jnius.find_javaclass (jnius/jnius.c:13171)
11-15 04:41:39.867 19683 19701 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: Class not found 'com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAd'
11-15 04:41:39.951 19683 19701 I python  : Python for android ended.
11-15 04:41:39.969 19683 19701 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1501
11-15 04:41:39.969 19683 19701 E AndroidRuntime: Process: intellign.ultimatepong:python, PID: 19683
11-15 04:41:39.969 19683 19701 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/intellign.ultimatepong-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/intellign.ultimatepong-1/lib/arm, /data/app/intellign.ultimatepong-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-15 04:41:39.969 19683 19701 E AndroidRuntime:        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-15 04:41:39.969 19683 19701 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-15 04:41:39.969 19683 19701 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
```

EDIT**: The banner test works but what I need is the rewarded ads which still does not work. Also line 59 in my main.py is: `ad_inst = Admob()`

```
11-15 19:48:56.971   345  3908 D WifiService: acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@4c670d8}
11-15 19:48:57.369 27702 27722 I Finsky  : [1841] com.google.android.finsky.l.c.a(23): Completed 0 account content syncs with 0 successful.
11-15 19:48:57.401 27702 27702 I Finsky  : [1] com.google.android.finsky.services.e.a(5): Installation state replication succeeded.
11-15 19:48:58.023  8254  8272 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
11-15 19:48:58.025  8254  8272 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 59, in <module>
11-15 19:48:58.028  8254  8272 I python  :    File "/home/kivy/Desktop/pong/.buildozer/android/app/admob/admob4android.py", line 61, in __init__
11-15 19:48:58.031  8254  8272 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 155, in jnius.jnius.JavaClass.__init__ (jnius/jnius.c:15030)
11-15 19:48:58.034  8254  8272 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 180, in jnius.jnius.JavaClass.call_constructor (jnius/jnius.c:15322)
11-15 19:48:58.036  8254  8272 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: No constructor available
11-15 19:48:58.152  8254  8272 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Comment: upload error logs as well

Comment: @AmodGokhale I updated the post with the error. Thank you

Comment: are you using latest google-play-services_lib ? it didn't find rewarded class defination in the lib file.

Comment: No and I think that is why, I will update it and let you know, thanks. Please check out my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47305550/python-for-android-in-app-purchase-kivy

Comment: @AmodGokhale Thanks for your patience. I updated the google play library but I think the error is from the Reward ads code i wrote.

Comment: Currently, Mobile Ads SDK doesn't officially support Kivy.. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/yNKNvdFdwG8 . You might want to open ticket with kivy. But if latest play services library is not updated for rewarded video. You might want to research for alternative advertisement platform

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking in right direction but to make it work you need RewardedVideoAdListener. You can create it using [PythonJavaClass](http://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jnius.PythonJavaClass) and [java methods](http://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jnius.java_method) from PyJnius like that:

```
from jnius import PythonJavaClass, java_method

from kivy.logger import Logger

from functools import partial

class RewardedVideoAdListener(PythonJavaClass):

    __javacontext__ = 'app'
    __javainterfaces__ = ["com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener"]

    __INFO = True

    @java_method('()V')
    def onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication(self):
        if self.__INFO:
            Logger.info("AdMob: onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication")

    @java_method('()V')
    def onRewardedVideoAdClosed(self):
        if self.__INFO:
            Logger.info("AdMob: onRewardedVideoAdClosed")

    @java_method('(I)V')
    def onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(self, errorCode):
        if self.__INFO:
            Logger.info("AdMob: onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad, errorCode is "+str(errorCode))

    @java_method('()V')
    def onRewardedVideoAdLoaded(self):
        if self.__INFO:
            Logger.info("AdMob: onRewardedVideoAdLoaded")

    @java_method('()V')
    def onRewardedVideoAdOpened(self):
        if self.__INFO:
            Logger.info("AdMob: onRewardedVideoAdOpened")

    @java_method('(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardItem;)V')
    def onRewarded(self, reward):
        if self.__INFO:
            Logger.info("AdMob: onRewarded, type is "+str(reward.getType())+", amount is "+str(reward.getAmount()))

    @java_method('()V')
    def onRewardedVideoStarted(self):
        if self.__INFO:
            Logger.info("AdMob: onRewardedVideoStarted")
```

Of course, you can add some handlers to this methods, for example:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial

@java_method('(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardItem;)V')
def onRewarded(self, reward):
    if self.__INFO:
        Logger.info("AdMob: onRewarded, type is "+str(reward.getType())+", amount is "+str(reward.getAmount()))
    self.__rewarded = True
    Clock.schedule_once(partial(on_reward, reward.getType(), reward.getAmount()))
```

And you have to use this listener in your setRewardedVideoAdListener method:

```
mRewardedVideoAdListener = RewardedVideoAdListener()
mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(mRewardedVideoAdListener)
```

Comment: I tried it but I think as @amod said, "Mobile Ads SDK doesn't officially support Kivy" Thank you very much for this though, it helped me understand alot